# Unable to show Modal when google map is shown in flutter

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PW2F.png)recently after updating to Flutter 3.10 the modalbottomsheet is not showing correctly, i am unable to show modal when google is shown. it hides the Appbar, and hides bottom of modal sheet too. anyone experience this issue too?  Please checked the attached picture.

Comment: There is no attached picture. Could you re-post the picture? Also provide the code-snippet so that developer could replicate the issue at their end.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, i have attaced te image, please check